# Develop an Instance Messaging chat functionality through server with Socket Programming in iOS

Tags: ios, xampp, livechat

I want to **develop an Instance Messaging chat functionality through server with Socket Programming** , but I don't know about `xampp server` and `server configuration`. I am making an iPhone application with Instance Messaging chat. Since I am new to `xampp server` its getting difficult for me. How to Develop an Instance Messaging chat functionality through server with Socket Programming?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple approach first using an external service like [firechat](http://firebase.github.io/firechat/) (which is built on top of firebase). You can build your own chat really easy, worrying only about the client part. The problem is that it's free only for a limited amount of users.

If you want something 100% free you can use the ejabberd. This has to be installed on top of XAMPP (for development environment) and is built with the JABBER/XMPP protocol (standar messaging protocol). This represents the server part of a chat application, now you need to worry about the client. You can test your server with any Chat app that is built for the same protocol (like iChat). To build your own chat client, use [this XMPP framework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS) for iOS. Everything is well documented.

One additional note. The second approach is MUCH MUCH more complicated (it was for me at least).

Hope this helps.